# Error: could not handle the request

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Estoy intentando hacer deploy a esta funcion en firebase para escribir un valor en cloud firestore cada cierto tiempo, me da error de Request: Error: could not handle the request

```javascript
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: 
      authDomain: 
    projectId: 
  });

  var Today = new Date();
  var Minutes = Today.getMinutes()
  var Boolean = true
  if (Minutes % 2 === 0) {
    Boolean = true
  }
  else {
    Boolean = false
  }
  var db = firebase.firestore();

  db.collection("users").doc("Booleanos").set({
    valor:Boolean
  })
  setTimeout(function(){location.reload()}, 6000);
});
```

Comment: El error te aparece al hacer el deploy o al llamar la función?

Comment: Luego de hacer el deploy, cuando lo ejecuto en mi Pc todo funciona OK.

Comment: Te muestra algo en los logs? `firebase functions:log`

Comment: Nada en los Logs. todo parece normal.

Comment: Dices que en el local te funciona sin problemas, pero al deployarlo te falla. No será que al inicializar Firebase, en donde deployas no estan los valores de configuración, que por lo general se manejan en un `.env`

Comment: Encontre esto en los resgistros de errores de functions.

~~~

ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
    at exports.time.functions.https.onRequest (/srv/index.js:5:3)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:49:9)
    at /worker/worker.js:783:7
    at /worker/worker.js:766:11
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)